# Why is ResourceBundle not loading after translating it in different language?

Tags: java, eclipse, resourcebundle

I have a properties file that is loaded just fine in Java7, Tomcat, Eclipse environment.

After translating it to a different language the file is not loaded by the server. During translation process a translator copied the file into docx file format and after translation, i tried to exporting it to plain `UTF8` properties file.

I believe some sort of character in the file is preventing it to load... i may be mistaken. anybody knows how i can figure out what is causing this?

Comment: Post the resource file if possible for best results.

Answer (score 0):

I created a java main function to load the file into Properties object.

```
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
    Properties data = new Properties();
    data.load(reader);
```

As a result of loading the file i received extiontion:

```
    IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
```

after searching for solution, i got a into a link asking me to search for "\u" in the file... sure thing I fount <\ul> in the properties file... and that was preventing JSF to load the resource bundle...